# Can number of matches in a regex be looped over?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following `regex` to find matches in a string that are 3 character matches for a pattern.

```
import re
s="banana"
print re.findall(r'(?=([^aeiou].{2}))',s,re.I)
```

Is it possible to loop through the regex (changing `{2}` in the above regex to be `{0},{1},{3},{4},{5}`) so i get all the character matches <= length of the string?

In this case i would like to get all the 1,2,3,4,5,6 character matches that don't start with a vowel.

The result would be

`['b', 'n', 'n','ba','na','na','ban','nan','bana','nana','banan','banana']`

Comment: Do you mean `{0,5}`?

Comment: using `{0,5}` would get me `['banana', 'nana', 'na']`. I am looking for all the 1,2,3,4,5,6 character matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply loop over the numbers in a for loop and format in the desired number with `%d`.

```
import re
s="banana"

result = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    part = re.findall(r'(?=([^aeiou].{%d}))'%i, s,re.I)
    result.extend(part)

print(result)
```

This will print out:

```
['b', 'n', 'n', 'ba', 'na', 'na', 'ban', 'nan', 'bana', 'nana', 'banan', 'banana']
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
import re
s = "banana"
for n in range(0, 6):
    print re.findall(r'(?=([^aeiou].{{{n}}}))'.format(n=n), s, re.I)
```

Demo:

```
>>> sum((re.findall(r'(?=([^aeiou].{{{n}}}))'.format(n=n), s, re.I) for n in range(6)), [])
['b',
 'n',
 'n',
 'ba',
 'na',
 'na',
 'ban',
 'nan',
 'bana',
 'nana',
 'banan',
 'banana']
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I appreciate it.